# Javascript decrypt key with RSA Public Key

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, rsa, cryptojs

Hi StackOverFlow Community.

First of all, its not a typo. Yup, I want to decrypt a hash message with the RSA Public Key. In my application, during login, the backend service will return me a RSA Public Key and I store it to decrypt the message in the future. The backend service will then send me a payload that was encrypted using the private key and I need to decrypt it using the public key.

Second, I use the [jsencrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsencrypt) library to perform this encryption/decryption process. For sending the payload to a backend service, I used the encrypt function which work flawlessly. But I am facing a trouble during decryption.

Third, I tried to decrypt the key sent from backend service using online tool such as [this](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/rsa-encryption-decryption) , the tools able to decrypt the hash message using the public key that I stored earlier.

For more information, this is how my code look a like currently

```
decryptPayload(response: any) {
  const key = response.key;
  const payload = response.payload;

  const publicRsaKey = sessionStorage.getItem('rsa_public_key');

  const rsaDecrypt = new JSEncrypt();
  rsaDecrypt.setPublicKey(`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
  ${publicRsaKey}
  -----END PUBLIC KEY-----`);
  const decryptAes = rsaDecrypt.decrypt(key);

  console.log('decryted key: ', decryptAes);
}
```

But the result of the `decrypted key` always return `false` which mean the decryption failed.

Does anyone ever did this before (decrypt using public key) using the same jsencrypt library ? And does we able to decrypt the hash message using the RSA public key ?

Comment: The proper terminology for what you are doing is 'signing' and 'verifying', not 'encrypt' and 'decrypt'. You would be advised to use a better library with higher level sign/verify primitives, and also with a documented API instead of just a single example. I will try to create an example with your code to see what is happening.

Comment: And, very simply, jsencrypt does not support this usage. jsencrypt only supports encrypting with the public key and decrypting with the private key.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk . Could you suggest a better library for me to use ? I cant find any that best and suit my requirement.

Comment: I googled and found this library -- https://github.com/JoshKaufman/ursa. I need your help to advise me on whether this library able to perform my requirement. Let me know what your thought Sir.